# Maven 3 with antlr3-maven-plugin: does source geneation really take place in process-sources?

Tags: maven-3, antlr3

I'm using antlr3-maven-plugin (v.3.3) with Maven 3. It has only one goal named `antlr` wchich, due to documentation:

> Binds by default to the lifecycle phase: generate-sources

However when I invoke `mvn generate-sources` the goal is never invoked. I need to invoke the next phase, `mvn process-sources` to activate this goal. What is going on.

Also, for me logging in mvn3 kinda sucks. I can't even see wchich goals was invoked in which phases, all I see is something like:

`[INFO] --- antlr3-maven-plugin:3.3:antlr (default) @ project ---`

But there is not info about the phase it happened, even if I execute Maven with -X flag! In mvn2 there was always info about current phase. Why such strange decision to reduce info in logs was taken by Maven team?

Comment: I'm only running mvn2, I just checked its definitely on generating on process-sources. Either a mistake in the docs or an error in the plugin implementation.

Comment: @nuzz Thanks a lot for confirming it! So I will file an issue!